In the following circuit, do T1 and T2 conduct or block when the circuit is in the LOW or HIGH state?

This circuit is a Schmitt trigger, and the supply voltage Ucc.​
is 15V. I want to calculate whether the transistors T1 and T2 are conducting or not when the state is LOW or HIGH(U(A)). These transistors are NPN bipolar junction transistors (BJTs). I suspect that in the LOW state, T1 blocks and T2 conducts, while it's the opposite in the HIGH state! For this, I used Kirchhoff's Voltage Law. Is the result correct?

It's not a Schmitt trigger; it's plain ordinary negative feedback. You need to provide a citation for the image. Use a simulator if you want to check this out for yourself.

@Andyaka - er, Andy - that's positive feedback from T2 emitter to T1 emitter. They are both NPN's.

You are right. Do you have an idea how this circuit works?

@KevinWhite you are so right. I must have had a brain fart.

It's just a diff (long tailed) pair wired as a schmitt (one bipolar diff in coming from the opposite bipolar's collector out.) Reference information is located here. If all that's needed is which bipolar is on or off, with respect to Vo, then it's kind of obvious. Clearly if Vo is near 15 V then T2 is off and T1 is on. If Vo is closer to ground (it won't reach ground, but perhaps a few volts above it), then T2 is on and T1 is off. How could it be otherwise? Out of which field this question comes? I've no idea. The answer is obvious.

@periblepsis, The differential pair is only one possible (but not the best) way to explain the Schmitt trigger. Here it is better to represent it as two cascaded CC and CB single-ended stages.

@Circuitfantasist I cannot agree with your perspective as being better. It's worse. To my eye. But that takes nothing away from whatever works for you. So long as the perspectives work equally well for either of us, and lacking any specific, narrowing context, then better is simply in the eye of the beholder.

@periblepsis, I won't argue. The truth is that the more points of view on a circuit, the better. I just drew attention to the fact that here the differential pair is not used as differential but as single ended.

@caramello209, Any reaction?

@Circuitfantasist Oh. Sure. And on that point I agree. It's single-ended input and single-ended output. But that's true for so many circuits -- uncountable -- that are also very different from each other. So different that knowing they are single ended I/O doesn't really help much. On the other hand, if someone tells me that this is a diff pair with one of the diff inputs tied to the other's collector output -- then that tells me a great deal about the circuit because I can leverage what I know about diff pairs and apply the ideas right away.

@periblepsis, Sure. I will even add a superlative - such an interlocutor is so rare here that I am tempted to insert one more observation. If you represent this circuit as a differential pair then someone would try to improve it by replacing the resistor in the emitter with a current source. I wonder what the result will be - will it be positive or negative? I'm trying to imagine it, and I can see that it probably won't make much of a difference.

@Circuitfantasist I have used this circuit where T2's collector goes straight into the base of another bipolar (VAS).  But there is an important purpose to T1's collector resistor. It converts the teeter-totter current to a managed voltage signal toward's T2's base. A current source wouldn't perform that function and T1's collector voltage would be in poorer management. (Haven't thought about it until you just now asked, though, because if the idea had flitted across my mind I would have discounted it as an unhelpful complexity, worried about the collector voltage, and then moved on.)

@periblepsis, I'm also thinking about it sitting on a bench under a vine, basking in the sun and not being able to stimulate it at the moment on my phone. I'm wondering if I should put in the effort to write a thoughtful response, even though I see that the OP doesn't really care. What would you do? BTW have you tried this circuit without base resistors? Interesting effects are obtained. They prompt us to end...

Here are some initial simulations.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
To simplify the schematic, collector resistors (Rc1 and Rc2) are represented by real ammeters with the same internal resistance (5 kΩ and 2 kΩ); the emitter resistor Re is represented by a voltmeter with 1 kΩ resistance.
Vin = 0V -> 4V

simulate this circuit
Vin = 4.1V -> 10V -> 2V

simulate this circuit
Vin = 0V -> 10V -> 0V

simulate this circuit


Strange thing - "Simulate this circuit" disappeared...

Aha... it's already appeared...
